# How to use reactive vars on server side

Tags: meteor

I want to use a reactive counter var on server side. But I can not guess how to do it without using collections.
I expect {{count}} will be updated after server count var changed without refresh a page or how to send a client that the count was changed?

```
<body>
  {{> test }}
</body>

<template name="test">
  {{count}}
</template>
```

client:

```
Meteor.call('count', function(err, result) {
  console.log(result)
  Session.set('count', result)
})

Template.test.helpers({
  count: function () {
    return Session.get('count')
  }
});
```

server:

```
var count=0

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    count++
  }, 1000)
});

Meteor.methods({
  count: function() {
    return count
  }
})
```

My code on [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/TBbQ4PTMpFn8gJCF9/A%20reative%20server%20var)

I want to see what I expect:

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('count')

Template.test.helpers({
  count: function () {
   return Counter.findOne().count
  }
});
```

Common:

```
Counter = new Mongo.Collection('count')
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('count', function() {
  return Counter.find()
})

Meteor.startup(function () {
  if(Counter.find().count() === 0) {
    Counter.insert({count: 0})
  }

  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    Counter.update({}, {$inc: {count: 1}})
  }, 1000)
});
```

Example on [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Lg5ay73gyQxG7ySbx/Counter%20using%20a%20collection)

Comment: What's the issue and what are you trying to do exactly? From what I see, you're incrementing a count every second then getting it on the client, and it works.

Comment: I expect that {{count}} will be updated after count var on the server changed without refresh a page.

Comment: Or how to send a client that the count was changed?

Comment: Well I'd most definitely use a Subscription... Let me check.

Comment: I've added other way to get what I want but I would like to manage changes by meteor server methods.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you plan to scale your application. If you plan to scale to multiple server instances then you cannot rely on the servers sharing information automatically. In this case it would be best to create a collection named something like "ApplicationState". Then every instance of your application can use a consistent state, and you can make use of the built in subscriptions.

If you plan to only use a single server instance then you should checkout the documentation on Tracker: http://manual.meteor.com/#tracker. This allows you to defined custom dependencies on data. I have not had the chance to play with it yet, but I am pretty sure that you can create something similar to subscriptions: http://manual.meteor.com/#deps-creatingreactivevalues

Comment: Thanks you for your detail explanation It will be very useful for my decision in the feature. Now I am playing around with Meteor on my easy project to get what I can make and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work as the way you want it because regular plain vars are not reactive data sources. The docs has a list of reactive data sources here http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity - So for your example to work you'd want to use Session or [ReactiveVar](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) - but these only works on the client so they wont help you here.

Your best bet is to create a manual publish function and subscribe to it from the client (or as other people has proposed, use a Collection - which would work across multiple servers as well). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I see now. I've found how to replace publish-count package and I've started to the wrong way before. My question about it http://goo.gl/ZkVIgq.